# xcode build fails with : "_RCTSetLogFunction", referenced from: -[AppTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in AppTests.o

Tags: ios, xcode, build, hyperlink

After upgrade xcode to 10.1 the project's compile fails with :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/divanov/Desktop/<projectName> AppTests'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_RCTSetLogFunction", referenced from:
      -[AppTests testRendersWelcomeScreen] in AppTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I fixed it with this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/25751/files

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following work around worked for me:

1. in XCode select the project in the left panel
2. Click on "Build Settings"
3. In the "Linking" section, find"Dead Code Stripping" section and change it "No"
4. Clean and Build

*** In another project I got the same error but in that case the libraries were missing in "Settings of the failing Target"/"Build Phases"/"Link Binary With", so I had to add them manually!

Comment: thanks! this worked, but may I know why changing "Dead Code Stripping" fixed this issue?

Comment: @RayJonathan I wish I can explain better but I cannot. My thinking at the time was : this is a linker issue post upgrade to newer version (and no code changes!) it must be something lingering from the previously generated binaries .. that option made most sense to me and it worked. Regardless - Apple can do a better job at those error messages..